# Problema de conexión al procesar la digitalizacion de cubo desde Visual Studio 2017 SSDT

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Por favor espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un problema de conexión a la base de datos cuando proceso la digitalización del cubo (BD Digitalizacion.cube) en visual studio 2017 SSDT.

Pero al inicio, cuando establecí un nuevo Origen de datos, me pude conectar a mi base de datos sin ningún problema y pude traer las tablas que necesitaba, no se porque a la hora de procesar la digitalizacion me sale error de conexión.

ERROR:
No se puede implementar el proyecto en el servidor 'DESKTOP-DOS0571\SQLEXPRESS' debido a los siguientes problemas de conexión:
'A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running.'.
Para comprobar o actualizar el nombre del servidor de destino, haga clic con el botón derecho del mouse (ratón) en el proyecto en el Explorador de soluciones, seleccione Propiedades del proyecto, haga clic en la pestaña Implementación y especifique el nombre del servidor.

Ya especifique el nombre del servidor y sigue saliendo el error.

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se si me he perdido en la explicación, pero la versión de [SQL Server Express](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/analysis-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016) no tiene implementadas las características de Analysis Services y por lo tanto no es posible implementar proyectos en el.

Comment: @RogerTorné Entonces cual version de SQL se de de usar?

Comment: @Riaven, necesitas la versión Standard, Enterprise o Developer. En [este enlace de la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/analysis-services/analysis-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016) lo podrás ver.

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, dando vueltas por sitios oficiales de microsoft, nunca mencionaron la incompatibilidad de SQLExpress con Analysis Services en las respuestas, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la version de SQL Server que instalaste, tuve el mismo problema y lo solucioné con lo siguiente:

1- Instalar SQL Server Modo Developer

2- En el momento de la instalación selecciona el Modo Personalizado

3- Sigue el instalador hasta el momento donde puedes seleccionar las features y asegurate de seleccionar el Analysis Services

4- Al momento de configurar el Ananalysis Services selecciona la opcion de Multidimensional y no la de Tabular (Error que yo cometí y pude arreglar)

De cualquier manera aca te dejo el video que seguí para la instalacion de SQL Server:

- https://youtu.be/kqr_UGOm-Zg

Y este por si el Anlaysis Services se les configura de forma Tabular:

- https://youtu.be/PSVBWnC6d2k